# Hasn’t it though?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Sorry I’m a beginner of English. May I ask what does “hasn’t it though” mean in a reply?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please show us some evidence of your own research on a question before asking it. For example, what do dictionaries tell you that you do not understand? Your question is better suited to English Language Learners Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Anton thanks for your comment! I’ll try to do that next time!

Comment: Please tell us the **original** preceding sentence. "His English has improved vastly." Response: Hasn't it though?

Answer (score -1):

In my experience it is a sarcastic, annoying version of the much more acceptable "Oh, hasn't it?" and would be part of a conversation like

*"Where's my green T-shirt?"*

*"It's in the washing machine and the programme hasn't finished yet"*

*"Hasn't it though!"*.

In the early 2000s it was teenager slang, if anyone is still using it it's probably time they grew up.

Comment: It is not necessarily sarcastic. It could be said admiringly too.

Comment: @Lambie I did say 'in my experience'.

Comment: @BoldBen If it's just in your experience, then it's better suited to a comment than an answer. Answers should be definitive